# $.ajaxSetup cache: What does that mean in jquery code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Today i have observed the following in a Jquery code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

What does this mean? And what happens if the value of cache turns `True`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> cache (`default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'`)
>   Type: **Boolean**
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.